# My week number 1 should start from 1 January for any year. How to do it in Python [pandas dataframe]?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

**I have dates in excel format as dataframe as shown below.**

## code

```
df = pd.DataFrame([44562.24909722, 44562.27255787, 44562.28564815],columns='orderdate'])
print(df)
```

## output

```
Out[255]: 
      orderdate
0  44562.249097
1  44562.272558
2  44562.285648
```

Then, I convert this excel date to real date using python function

## code

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.orderdate, unit='D', origin='1899-12-30')

Out[258]: 
     orderdate               date
0  44562.249097 2022-01-01 05:58:41.999808256
1  44562.272558 2022-01-01 06:32:28.999967744
2  44562.285648 2022-01-01 06:51:20.000159744
```

Now, I have to extract week numbers from the following date column. I use:
#code

```
df['weekno'] = df.date.dt.isocalendar().week
```

## Output

```
     orderdate               date                weekno
0  44562.249097 2022-01-01 05:58:41.999808256      52
1  44562.272558 2022-01-01 06:32:28.999967744      52
2  44562.285648 2022-01-01 06:51:20.000159744      52
```

**So, in the output, I get weekno = 52 for 1 January 2022.  I understand this is a isocalendar format. But I want my week number 1 to start from 1 January every year. How to do that ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using strftime like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame([44562.24909722, 44562.27255787, 44562.28564815],columns=['orderdate'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.orderdate, unit='D', origin='1899-12-30')

# This line is new
df['week_of_year'] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: int(x.strftime("%W")))
print(df)
```

Output

```
      orderdate                          date week_of_year
0  44562.249097 2022-01-01 05:58:41.999808256           0
1  44562.272558 2022-01-01 06:32:28.999967744           0
2  44562.285648 2022-01-01 06:51:20.000159744           0
```

This will give you the week starting at Monday, and the first week of the year is `0`.

Now, if you absolutely need the first week to start at 1, simply add 1 :)

```py
df['week_of_year'] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: int(x.strftime("%W"))+1)
```

Output:

```py
      orderdate                          date  week_of_year
0  44562.249097 2022-01-01 05:58:41.999808256             1
1  44562.272558 2022-01-01 06:32:28.999967744             1
2  44562.285648 2022-01-01 06:51:20.000159744             1
```

P.S. You can check this [useful tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime) on `strftime`. I find it a much more flexible tool for parsing dates than `panda`'s included one.